# How to have the selected state of a UIButton change before the method is called?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm calling a method from a uibutton (an array of uibuttons in this case). The problem is that the button should change its `UIControlStateSelected` immediately and display a new uiimage for the button. It shows the image but only after running the method. The method downloads some data and takes a second or two. The user obviously isn't sure if they touched the button or not in that case until the method is called and the button image selected state changes the image.

Here's the code I'm using for the button(s) selected state:

```
        [catBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [catBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[categoryBtnImages objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [catBtn setTitle:@"I'm selected" forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        [catBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[categoryBtnImagesSel objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
     //   NSLog(@"%@",[categoryBtnImagesSel objectAtIndex:i]);

        [catBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [catButtonArray addObject:catBtn];
```

thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best guess given only partial `IBACTION` code:

If you are performing an synchronous download in the button's `IBACTION` method that is keeping the UI from updating the button. Perform the download with an asynchronous download method so the `IBACTION` method can complete and the button can update.

The `NSURLConnection` method `sendAsynchronousRequest` is an easy way to perform an async download:

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
  queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue
  completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler
```

Answer (score 3):

The interface should never be blocked like that. Imagine the frustration of the user wondering what is happening while the button gets pressed. Imagine yourself thinking whether you pressed it or not. If it takes a second or two, it should be done outside of the main thread, so the interface doesn't freeze and the user immediately knows what is going on.

If you are trying to download something, you should certainly look at the [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
docs page, and use the `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the 'loading' code into a seperate method.

Then you call this loading method from within the action method by

```
[self performSelector:@selector(loadingMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

Comment: [self performSelector:@selector(buttonPressed:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];